# Using php pre_match to find not consecutive blocks of equal characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string of variable length with only "0" and "1" characters, for example: "1101"

I want to check if there exists more than one contiguous block of "1"s.

I'm using preg_match function of PHP.

Some examples:

```
"0000" no matches

"1100" no matches

"1101" match
```

Can you suggest a regular expression?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! How much do you know about regular expressions? What have you tried?

Comment: You don't have to use a regex to do that: `if ( strpos(trim('1101', '0'), '0') ) {...`

Comment: Thank you @Docteur I know vey little regular expressions, somtimes I used them googlin around but I can't find a solution to my actual problem.  I tried somthing like preg_match("/10*1/", $key, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 1); but it doesn't work.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte may be I haven't explained well my problem but those strings are only examples. Lengths of strings may change and number of zeros can change, as far as I can understand, I need regular expressions. Obviously I could loop through the string but I'm trying to learn this kind of technique.

Comment: @MarcoCagnoli: my solution works for any length of string and any number of zeroes.

Comment: Please see my answer @MarcoCagnoli. I recommend you go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well so that you can ask high-quality questions in the future.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte wow.... you're in right ;-) thank you!

Comment: @Docteur yes, I'm studying your answer and yes, I'll take a deep look to the tour. Thank you for the collaboration.

Comment: You can also check at the same time if the string contains only 0s and 1s using `count_chars`: `if ( count_chars(trim('1101', '0'), 3) == '01' ) {...`

Comment: @MarcoCagnoli You're welcome. Remember to accept the answer you think answers best your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without using a regex:

```
if ( strpos(trim($str, '0'), '0') ) { //...
```

or if you also need to check that the string only contains 0s and 1s:

```
if ( count_chars(trim($str, '0'), 3) == '01' ) { //...
```

The idea is the same for these two tests: the `trim` function removes all the zeroes at the boundaries, and the second function proves that there's at least one remaining zero (prisoner between 1s).

It can also be done with `preg_match`:

```
if ( preg_match('~10+1~', $str) ) { //...
```

or if you want to check all the string:

```
if ( preg_match('~^0*1+0+1[01]*$~D', $str) ) { //...
```

*(The D modifier forces `$` to only match the end of the string and not at the end of the last line before a trailing newline.)*

Comment: Nice trick with strpos!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
/^1+0+[01]*1+$/

That means:
^1+: Starts with at least one "1"
0+: Followed by at least one "0"
[01]*: could contain a variable number of "0" or "1" 
1+$: Has to end with at least one "1"

This matches:
1011
1101

This does not match:
0000
1111
1100
```

If it does not need to end with a "1" this would fit:

```
/^1+0+1+[01]*$/

This matches:
1011
1101
11010
10110

This does not match:
0000
1111
1100
```

Or that:

```
/^((1+0+1)|(0+1+0+))+[01]*$/

This matches:
1011
1101
11010
10110
01000
00010

This does not match:
0000
1111
1100
01111
00011
```

Comment: The matches aren't very good when it comes to, for example, 01010. Your regex doesn't match everything.

Comment: @Docteur I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
0*(?:1+0+1+)+[01]*
```

Explanation:

```
0* Matches 0 to n "0"
(?: Starts a non-matching group
1+ Matches at least one "1"
0+ Matches at least one "0"
1+ Matches at least one "1"
)+ Matches at least one of the group
[01]* Matches any left-over digits
```

This will work for your examples, as well as :

```
010111001011 Matches
100101 Matches
0111001 Matches
1110 Doesn't match
001100000 Doesn't match
```